# Can show a view as part of another view in MVC

Tags: c#

Hi i'm quite new with C# MVC,
i have a trouble like that

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Trang Chủ", "Index", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Giới Thiệu", "About", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tin Tức", "News", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Thăng Hạng", "Upgrade", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Thẻ Loyalty", "Card", "Home")</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tích Điểm", "Point", "Home")</li>
    </ul>
    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

it's in _layout.cshtml, those link now i'm hard code.
In database it containt those link.
Now i want to create a view & controller to display it

Controller

```
 public ActionResult MenuFront()
 {return View(db.Loyalty_MenuFront.Where(m => m.MenuType == 1 && m.Display == 1 && m.ParentID == 0));}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MPLoyalty_MVC.Models.Loyalty_MenuFront>
@{foreach (var item in Model)
{<li>@Html.ActionLink("" + item.Name, "" + item.Method, "" + item.Controller)</li>}}
```

But it doesnt work. Can anyone help me, please.Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your code here instead of images?

Comment: *But it doesnt work.* Does not help anyone.. Can you post the error/exception message

Comment: i use @Html.Action("MenuFront") instead of the hard code then it catch overload exception. Coz the _layout load an infinity loop at MenuFront()

Answer (score 0):

I believe your partial view might be saved under the wrong folder in your solution.  It should either be in the same folder as your view, or it should be under the "Views" > "Shared" folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank u guys,
I have use ajax to solve it

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/MenuFront",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
                $("#menu").append('<li><a href="/' + data[i].controller + '/' + data[i].method + '">' + data[i].name + '</a></li>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```
public ActionResult MenuFront()
    {
        var menu = db.Loyalty_MenuFront.Where(m => m.MenuType == 1 && m.Display == 1 && m.ParentID == 0)
            .Select (m => new { 
                name = m.Name, 
                method = m.Method, 
                controller = m.Controller
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(menu);
    }
```